# Stripe CLI Connection to remote host denied

Tags: php, stripe-payments, webhooks

I created the localhost alias webhook on the stripe dashboard, in my command promt i ran the listener fro Stripe CLI

```
C:\MAMP\htdocs\bla> stripe listen --load-from-webhooks-api --forward-to https://bla.dev.com --skip-verify              
> Ready! You are using Stripe API Version [2022-08-01]. Your webhook signing secret is whsec_XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX55 (^C to quit)
```

when i test the payments i get this in my command prompt

```
2022-12-14 15:16:25   --> checkout.session.completed [evt_1MEpCWDT9pjYXXXXX]  
2022-12-14 15:16:25  <--  [200] POST https://bla.dev.com/frontend/web/payment/stripe/endpoint/ [evt_3MEpCKDT9pjYPnbXXXX]
2022-12-14 15:16:25   --> charge.succeeded [evt_3MEpCKDT9pjYXXXXXX]
2022-12-14 15:16:26  <--  [200] POST https://bla.dev.com/frontend/web/payment/stripe/checkout/endpoint/ [evt_1MEpCWDT9pXXXXX]
```

but when i check my stripe dashboard, it shows this error

```
Connection to remote host denied (please contact support at https://support.stripe.com/contact/)
```

The url `https://bla.dev.com/frontend/web/payment/stripe/endpoint/` is valid Alias, when i type it into browser i get a `405` error, because it only allows `POST`

Any idea how to fix this? it worked before, not sure what broke.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forwarding the events in CLI to Webhook URL and setting Webhook URL in Dashboard are two different locations to Stripe and the event will be sent to both.

1. Forwarding the event from CLI goes through: Stripe -> local -> Your
   webhook URL
2. Setting Webhook URL in Dashboard has events goes through: Stripe -> Your webhook URL

With `Connection to remote host denied`, it's likely that your Webhook URL is not publicly accessible. Common reason can be that the domain is not accessible from external and only works in your location machine.

Comment: So, if it's not exposed to public. I can refer to the 200 status in command prompt to know it works then?

Comment: Forwarding makes the URL accessible to your local machine only, the URL is still not accessible to Stripe or any other devices.

Comment: @qichuan understand, so safe to assume that the `200` i get means if the website is live, the webhook would work accordingly then?